# Data structure in Autotrain for bert-base-uncased

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface, fine-tuning

wanna use autotrain from huggingface to finetune pretrain model(bert-base-uncased) ,and it just keeps giving me this error : json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 9 column 1 (char 171)

i prepare my dataset like this [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsmC6.png)which works for disstillbert , but not for bert-base-uncased and Robert-based

does anybody know the data structure for bert-base-uncased , thank you so much !!!